# NPM fails during `npm install` with 'npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded' error

Tags: wordpress, npm, wordpress-plugin-creation, vvv-wordpress

I am developing a fork of a popular wordpress plugin (Sensei-lms) ... the plugin developers have given instructions for creating a development environment on this page: https://github.com/Automattic/sensei/wiki/Setting-Up-Your-Development-Environment#configure-a-local-wordpress-instance

I have created a clean instance as described in the instructions and cloned the git repo

However on running the `npm install` command I always get the following errors:

```
vagrant@vvv:/srv/www/wordpress-one/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sensei$ npm install
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2021-09-07T03_45_45_825Z-debug.log
```

The log files don't really give any indication of problem other than repeating the problem ...

```
19886 verbose stack RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
19886 verbose stack     at RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
19886 verbose stack     at isDepOptional (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:432:45)
19886 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:441:9)
19886 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
19886 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
19886 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
19886 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
19886 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
19886 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
19886 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
19886 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
19886 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
19886 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
19886 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
19886 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
19886 verbose stack     at failedDependency (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:9)
19887 verbose cwd /srv/www/sensei/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sensei-lms
19888 verbose Linux 5.4.0-80-generic
19889 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
19890 verbose node v14.17.6
19891 verbose npm  v6.14.15
19892 error Maximum call stack size exceeded
19893 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

From my reading it seems that the iteration of dependancies being installed has reached it's limit.

I have tried all the of the following without luck:

> 1: as per multiple blogs and articles advising to do so
>
> ```
> vagrant@vvv:...$ cd /srv/www/wordpress-one/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sensei
> vagrant@vvv:...$ rm -fr /usr/lib/node_modules
> vagrant@vvv:...$ rm -fr node_modules/
> vagrant@vvv:...$ npm cache clean --force 
> vagrant@vvv:...$ npm rebuild
> vagrant@vvv:...$ rm package-lock.json
> vagrant@vvv:...$ npm install
> ```

> 2: as per http://pyha.ru/forum/topic/9396.1
>
> ```
> vagrant@vvv:...$ cd /srv/www/wordpress-one/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sensei
> vagrant@vvv:...$ rm -fr /usr/lib/node_modules
> vagrant@vvv:...$ rm -fr node_modules/
> vagrant@vvv:...$ npm cache clean --force 
> vagrant@vvv:...$ node --stack-size=10000 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install
> ```

Any further help - what might I be doing wrong?

---

Further to this above issue:

1. I'm running VVV on Macbook Pro and the default setup creates a VVV machine running a bento box of Ubuntu  20.04.3 LTS with a npm 6.14.15 version (from nodejs package version: 14.17.6-deb-1nodesource1)
2. I've destroyed the VVV instance and started again to work from clean without any issues I might have created in earlier tries - still fails !
3. I've gone to my desktop linux machine (different machine from the mac running VVV) - the linux desktop is running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS natively with default apt install of npm 6.14.4 version (from nodejs package version: 10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1) and with a clean sensei `git clone` and `npm install` works fine !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem the issue lies with Vagrant (or even VirtualBox) and not npm or sensei....

In a quick google search I discovered the following article: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/otto-next-generation-vagrant which mentions (emphasis mine):

> Vagrant is far from dead, but it suffers from a couple of long-lasting
> issues, including the resource footprint of virtual machines created,
> **the speed of sharing files between the host and virtual machine**, and
> the speed of making configuration changes to virtual machines.

This made me think if I could run npm on the virtualbox in a folder not shared through to the host machine.... as follows:

> ```
> vagrant@vvv:~$ pwd
>    /home/vagrant
> vagrant@vvv:~$ git clone https://github.com/Automattic/sensei.git
> vagrant@vvv:~$ cd sensei/
> vagrant@vvv:~$ npm install
> ```

***And it worked!***

So the next step was to copy the successful node_modules folder from the non-shared folder to the public_html folder and build the assets :

> ```
> vagrant@vvv:...$ cd /srv/www/wordpress-one/public_html/wp-content/plugins/
> vagrant@vvv:...$ git clone https://github.com/Automattic/sensei.git
> vagrant@vvv:...$ cd sensei/
> vagrant@vvv:...$ mv ~/sensei/node_modules/ .
> vagrant@vvv:...$ npm run build:assets
> ```

The `mv` took a long time but it worked !

Not sure what will happen down the track if I need to run npm install again but we'll cross that bridge when we come to it.

At least we are working....